# Running an exe in recursive folders

Tags: powershell, windows-7

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted
$start_path ="D:\VST\"
$start_path> Get-ChildItem-Recurse |
foreach { cd $_.DirectoryName; "VST_Screenshot_Tool"; cd ..; }
```

This is supposed to run `VST_Screenshot_Tool.exe` in the root and all subfolders at `$start_path`.  I get this error:

```
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
At C:\Users\pithy\Desktop\screenshotter.ps1:2 char:13
+ $start_path  <<<< ="D:\ZZ_AUDIO\VST etc\__ARCHIVE\*" |
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [],       ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

Any pointers would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$start_path> Get-ChildItem-Recurse` would write the string `D:\VST\` to the file `Get-ChildItem-Recurse` in the current directory. Also, you need the call operator (`&`) for executing command strings, and you should include the extension if you want to run external commands. Without the operator PowerShell will simply echo the string.

Change your code to this:

```
$start_path = 'D:\VST'

Get-ChildItem $start_path -Recurse -Directory | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Location $_.FullName
  & "VST_Screenshot_Tool.exe"
}
```

On PowerShell v2 and earlier you need to substitute the `-Directory` parameter like this:

```
Get-ChildItem $start_path -Recurse | Where-Object {
  $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
  Set-Location $_.FullName
  & "VST_Screenshot_Tool.exe"
}
```